# Reshaping dataframes

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

Suppose I have this untidy dataframe with rownames

```
df<-data.frame(A=rnorm(2),B=rnorm(2),C=rnorm(2))
rownames(df)<-c('male','female')
> df                
            A         B          C
male   0.10138957  1.036535  2.0708251
female 0.08524181 -1.140275 -0.3800585
```

I'd like to get it into to tidy form such that the columns `A`, `B`, and `C` are collapsed into a single column and there's an additional column for `Gender`. It might look like this

```
> desired_df
   where    value   Gender
1    A  0.10138957   male
2    A  0.08524181 female
3    B  1.03653464   male
4    B -1.14027549 female
5    C  2.07082513   male
6    C -0.38005851 female
```

Here's one way to achieve this using `tidyr`.

```
desired_df<-gather(df,where,value)
desired_df['Gender']<-rep(c('male','female'),nrow(df)/2)
```

But I had to convert the row names into a column in a rather inelegant way. My question is - What additional functions in `tidyr` or `reshape` would have helped with this? Or could my call to `gather` have been done differently in order to achieve this result in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get to your "desired_df" in several ways. Here's one with "dplyr" and "tidyr" where we combine the steps a little more conveniently:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% cbind(rn = rownames(df)) %>% gather(where, value, A:C)
```

Or, you can use the `matrix` method for `melt` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
melt(as.matrix(df))
#     Var1 Var2       value
# 1   male    A -1.58936590
# 2 female    A -2.11861101
# 3   male    B -0.04883463
# 4 female    B  1.77685001
# 5   male    C  0.22472189
# 6 female    C  1.35717680
```

In base R, you can use `stack` and just recycle the `rownames`:

```
cbind(rn = rownames(df), stack(df))
#       rn      values ind
# 1   male -1.58936590   A
# 2 female -2.11861101   A
# 3   male -0.04883463   B
# 4 female  1.77685001   B
# 5   male  0.22472189   C
# 6 female  1.35717680   C
```

Or, with some slight trickery, making use of the `data.frame` method for `table`s, you can do:

```
data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(df)))
#     Var1 Var2        Freq
# 1   male    A -1.58936590
# 2 female    A -2.11861101
# 3   male    B -0.04883463
# 4 female    B  1.77685001
# 5   male    C  0.22472189
# 6 female    C  1.35717680
```

Comment: I'd avoid using `cbind()` like this - it's a bit of a trap because you never know what `cbind()` is going to return (a matrix or a data frame?). I'd use `data.frame()` instead.

Comment: @hadley, Not sure I understand your comment. Both `gather` and `stack` would return `data.frame`s, meaning we know exactly what `cbind` will return. Or is there a chance that `gather` does not return a `data.frame` that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: I just meant that it's risky to use `cbind()` in general, because it has poorly defined semantics (in the same way it's generally better to avoid `sapply()`)

Comment: e.g. you see a lot of people doing `cbind(letters, 1:26)` which doesn't do what they expect

Comment: thanks @AnandaMahto - didn't realize `melt` had different method for `matrix` than `data.frame`.